# Kendo UI AngularJs Multiple Controllers on the Page

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I 'm new to Kendo UI and AngularJS 
 I need some help / examples, how to use multiple controllers on the same page like below

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["kendo.directives"])

app.controller("MyCtrlA", function ($scope) {
    $scope.loadStockData = {

    }

app.controller("MyCtrlB", function ($scope) {
    $scope.loadCustomerData = {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just set the ng-controller on whatever parent html node you want to.  You can use as many controllers as you want on a page.

Here is a page with 3 controllers, displaying a message off of each controllers $scope.

http://jsbin.com/xokoqa/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yeah good Example i was trying the same way , but I was missing semi-colon between controllers in java script...